# SpecFlow: Associated Automation not showing Tests in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, automated-tests, specflow

I have a Selenium solution with approximately 40 tests.  In Visual Studio 2015, when I navigate to Work Items, search for a test case I want to link a test to, click the Associated Automation tab, and then click the ellipsis in the Automated Test Name field, I see a choose test window with a list of Test Names and Test Ids I can select.

In a SpecFlow solution that also uses Selenium that I was just handed. When I repeat these steps, the choose test window is empty.  Both solutions have been checked into source control.  The Selenium tests were once part of a project that was in a Build, but the project has extracted several months ago and now simply reside in Source Control.

Is there something different about SpecFlow that I need to do to be able to associate the test code with the TFS test cases?

Picture Of Available Tests to Link to in SpecFlow Solution:
[image]

Comment: Which unit test runner are you using?

Comment: SpecFlow.NUnit
<package id="SpecFlow.NUnit" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: You can only use MSTest TestMethods in associated automations. There seems to have been some work on this lately: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2956423-allow-all-unit-test-types-to-be-associated-to-a-wo. But it looks like VS cannot discover NUnit tests when you wan't to associate them to a test case as an associated automation, see this queston also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410387/nunit-tests-dont-appear-in-tfs-choose-test-dialog-using-visual-studio-2013-c. Why do you need to associate your NUnit tests with a Test Case work item?

Comment: Associating a unit/automated test with a Test Case is the only way to change the Automation Status to Automated in TFS.  This is what I'm using to separate our manual regression tests from our automation suite.